# Is this variant of Exact Path Length Problem easy or NP Complete

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

I was reading about the longest path problem and it is NP Complete.

What about the problem where we need to find a path of some exact length $K$. All edges are directed. We are also allowed to repeat edges and vertices and all weights are positive.

The reason is where ever I look they in the definition emphasize:

1. Simple paths or
2. Weights are both positive and negative.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0196677401912015

So I wonder if those 2 conditions are necessary for NP Completeness.

Comment: any directed graph. i mean other than a vertex having a direct edge to itself or the graph being disconnected pretty much any general graph not just digraphs.

Comment: It's NP-hard by reduction from subset sum.

Comment: @Dmitry I am struggling to see how.. can you please elaborate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem - In subset sum we are given a fixed multiset (am I correct?) here I can repeat any edge any number of times. so doesn't it make them different ?

Comment: If you construct a DAG, then you will be able to use an edge only once.

Comment: moreover there the ordering does not matter.. any sub set is a valid potential answer.. here a path may not exist (depending on the edge's direction, or if the edge exists at all)?

Comment: Well, then your reduction should construct a graph where the path exists.

Comment: yes but that changes the problem and still there is the issue of all values can form a valid subset.. but a path may or may not exist (ordering matters) and so does existence of edges!

Comment: I am not understanding these succinct comments at all.. can you please elaborate in one full comment

Comment: Am I missing something; you can just iterate K down, then take the max that has a path.  The possible Ks (barring infinite loops) is polynomial in graph size?

Comment: @Yakk No, the number of possible values of $K$ is not polynomial in the graph size, even without cycles.

Comment: @Nathaniel Got it; just give each edge a (1<<X) value, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for simple paths for the longest path problem is simple (pun not intended):

- either there is a cycle of positive weight, and therefore the longest path is not really defined as it could have an infinite weight;
- or all cycles have non-positive weight, and the longest path is a simple path.

As for weight values, if you can find a longest path in a graph with positive and negative weights, you can also do it in a graph with only positive weights (because no negative weights is only a particular case).

As for the exact weight path problem, it is also $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. There is a possible reduction from the Hamiltonian path problem.

Given a digraph $G = (V, E)$ with $V=\{v_1, …, v_n\}$, consider $G' = (V', E', f)$ such that:

- $V' = \{v_{i,k}\mid i,k \in \{1, …, n\}\} \cup \{s, t\}$;
- $E' = \{(v_{i,k}, v_{j,k+1})\mid k\in \{1, …, n-1\} \text{ and }(v_i, v_j)\in E\}\cup \{(s, v_{i,1})\mid i\in \{1, …, n\}\}\cup \{(v_{i,n}, t)\mid i\in \{1, …, n\}\}$;
- for $e = (u, v)\in E'$, $f(e) = n^i$ if $v=v_{i,k}$ and $f(e) = 1$ if $v = t$.

Then I claim (if I am not mistaken) that there exists a Hamiltonian path in $G$ if and only if there exists a path of weight $W=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n n^i$ in $G'$. The idea is that given that the second index is incremented in each edge, a path in $G'$ can only contain at most $n+1$ edges (from $s$ to $t$). Also, it is not possible to cross two edges of the same weight twice (otherwise it would not be possible to get the total weight $W$).

Comment: Thank you. I understand. But this is regarding longest path. what about exact path. In that too it mentions negative and positive weights. why not just positive? for some similar reason (i don't see it why)?

Comment: if possible can you please clarify regarding exact path version too?

Comment: @student0 sorry, it was harder than I thought to find a reduction. I hope I did not make any mistake.

Answer (score 5):

It's NP-complete even with weights from $\mathbb N$, and polytime for unweighted.

Reference: *On the difficulty of finding walks of length $k$*, Basagni, Bruschi, Ravasio (1997).

The reduction is from Subset Sum (it's not trivial to see how it is even in NP, since a walk can be exponential in the input size), but they give a reasonable encoding.

The problem remains NP-hard on undirected graphs and even DAGs.